Permission Denied error in starting container
I’m encountering a permission denied error in OpenShift container where my Argo CD pod is failing to start. The error message indicates that the container failed due to permission issues. How can I resolve this?
Pod does not start up successfully because of Permission denied This is my Docker file
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN chgrp -R 0 /app && \
    chmod -R g=u /app


RUN pip install flask

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "src/test.py"]
CMD ["python", "src/test.py"]

It is running with minikube, deployment is successful but in open shift so Anyone can help me with this?
Current Result
Pod does not start up successfully because of Permission denied
Expected Result
Pod to start successfully

What is the exact error message? You said that "your argocd pod is failing to start", but the Dockerfile you show here has nothing to do with argocd.

Permission denied, container fail to start

And the docker file I posted here because I guess the permission denied is because of SCC restricted So I in docker file I added the part where you can write/read as any user but this thing still doesn't work

If it's an SCC issue, you will see that information in the output of oc get events.

Back-off restarting failed container app1 in pod and in logs just permission denied so I assume that's because of SCC,, but can't get more info in logs or in events

Try adding USER 1001 before the ENTRYPOINT instruction in the dockerfile, also there is no need to declare both ENTRYPOINT and CMD in the same way, only the ENTRYPOINT instruction is sufficient.

I already added 1001 in docker file but that doesn't change anything. Do I have to add anything in deployment manifest also?
